# Why Opera is using Firefox's Cookies

Tags: php, firefox, cookies, file-upload, opera

I have two open sessions on different browsers (**Firefox**, **Opera**). Both of them **run on different user accounts**. When I navigate through the administration page, the cookies are ok. But when I try to upload some images, **the uploading php script receives the same cookies as in Firefox**.

This doesn't happen if I use Internet Explorer instead of **Opera**.

Comment: How are you uploading the images?  Through a flash or Java uploader?  Or through a HTML form?

Comment: Can you check the cookies in both browsers and assure yourself that this is indeed a cookie issue, and not the remote end using IP address to identify you?

Comment: I'm using Uploadify which is uploading files through a flash script.

Comment: I've checked the cookies on both browsers, on the page they are using different cookies, but in the script they use the same (I've dumped the $_COOKIE to see the values from the uploading php script).

Comment: It seems that something is wrong with the code somewhere, because now Firefox is borrowing Internet Explorer's cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Flash - which it seems like you do - this is because all browsers share Flash cookies since they're stored in the same location on the computer. This is not a browser problem, but rather a Flash problem (or feature).

---

**Edit**: See [Local Shared Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Shared_Object) on Wikipedia for a bit more information about Flash cookies.